# CSS: Is there a way to detect using only CSS when all checkboxes in a form are checked?

Tags: css, checkbox

I have the following form:

```
<form>
  <div class="form-check">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="defaultCheck1">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="defaultCheck1">
      One.
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-check">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="defaultCheck2">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="defaultCheck2">
      Two.
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-check">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="defaultCheck3">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="defaultCheck3">
      Three.
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-check">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="defaultCheck4">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="defaultCheck4">
      Four.
    </label>
  </div>
</form>
```

I understand that I can use the following to style checkboxes that are checked:

```
.form-check-input:checked + label {
  color: blue
}
```

I have a form with a varying number of multiple checkboxes. Is there a way to apply the style only if all checkboxes in a form are checked?

I would like to do this in CSS only.

Comment: 1) apply the style to what? 2) share your markup

Comment: not with current css and definately not with that html structure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all of your checkboxes are `required` you can leverage the `:valid` pseudo-class on the form to select it or any of its descendants.

Else as @Pete said there is currently no way to do it.

Comment: I added `required` to all of the inputs and used the `form:valid` selector.

Comment: I hope you're aware it will prevent your form's submission if all checkboxes aren't checked?